# Java foreach NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, iteration, java-7

The other days we found a rather awkward exception in the logs of our application in this piece of code:

```
 final LIST currentSinks = this.sinks;
 if (null != currentSinks && !currentSinks.isEmpty())
 {
     for (final DataSink<? super T> sink : currentSinks)// **the exception is thrown here**
     {
         sink.updated(oldValue, newValue);
     }
 }
```

where **LIST** is

```
public abstract class AbstractDataSource<T, LIST extends Collection<DataSink<? super T>>>
```

The implementation used is ArrayList. It just throws [NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html). To be honest I don't really understand why. Whatever I tried just had the expected behavior: no iteration through the for.

The stack trace's first line:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException caught here: java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:834)

Any hint or explanation would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Probably a good starting point would be to isolate the behavior in a UT. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: post reproducible code and stacktrace

Comment: Thread concurrency error, I bet.

Comment: Impossible to help from the information provided.

Comment: I'm with @FilipeBorges, probably another thread removed an element between the Iterator's `hasNext()` and `next()` call. That or a buggy Iterator implementation. What type is `list`?

Comment: what is the type of `list`? What does it contain? What are you doing in the `for` loop. You can't modify the `Iterable` inside such loop...

Comment: We need more information.  Like, what is the runtime type of "list". If it isn't a standard JDK class, what does the Iterator returned look like?  Is this multithreaded code, etc...

Comment: @JigarJoshi - I would love to have reproducible code, it doesn't reproduce in a consistent manner. Please see the changes code snapshots.

Comment: The fact that you say it doesn't reproduce in a consistent manner makes it much more likely to be a multithreading-related issue.

Comment: @FilipeBorges - in case a collection is modified after an **Iterator** is created, shouldn't it throw a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)?

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri - wouldn't a modification of a collection after the creation of the iterator make the Iterator.next() throw a ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: Not necessarily, see @SteveKuo's explanation. An item could have been removed after the iterator checked for elements using `hasNext()` and just before calling `next()`. In this case the probability would be that the threading issue causes the `NoSuchElementException` before the method detects a concurrent modification.

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri - yes, it might based on the (source code)[http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html]. Thank you!

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP just to check again, are you using jdk 1.5?

Comment: @FilipeBorges - actually it's JDK 7, sorry for the misstag :(

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP isolating the behavior in a unit test is probably the best way to solve a bug. Please let me know when you achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I will make the effort o sum up what was discussed in the comments. Thanks everyone and fell free to edit this answer.

The error description feels like a concurrency error, so our theory is:

> probably another thread removed an element between the Iterator's `hasNext()` and `next()` call, that happens behind the scenes in the `for(:)` loop (thanks Steve!).

So, lets test our theory:

1) First of all, `list` type is `ArrayList` and from ArrayList docs we have:

> ArrayList is not synchronized, so if you need multi-threaded access,  consider using `List l = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));`

2) Then we check source code to find references to `NoSuchElementException`: no occurrence found on [`java.util.ArrayList.java`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/ArrayList-source.html), but five occurrences in [`java.util.AbstractList.java`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/AbstractList-source.html), which the most interesting is:

```
   // under: public ListIterator<E> listIterator(final int index) {
   //        return new ListIterator<E>() {
   // line 1040:
   /**
   * Retrieves the next object from the list.
   *
   * @return The next object.
   * @throws NoSuchElementException if there are no
   *         more objects to retrieve.
   * @throws ConcurrentModificationException if the
   *         list has been modified elsewhere.
   */
  public E next()
  {
      if (position == size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
      position++;
      return i.next();
  }
```

Back to our theory we can say that:

- Yes, it is possible. `ArrayList` is not synchronized (1) and there is a point where a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown by an `iterator.next()` before any concurrent modification check (2).
- It can only be proved when you find the source of problem and reproduce it (a UT is probably the best option). Until that, probably this is your best bet anyway.

Hope it helps you solve your problem!

Comment: Make a checked single-thread proxy for ArrayList and use that instead. By checked single-thread I mean it holds an `AtomicReference<Thread> myThread`. Before any call, it does `myThread.compareAndSet(null, Thread.currentThread()`. If it fails, it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Then, it doeas `myThread.set(null)` upon return. When the debugger breaks for the exception, you will be in one of the concurrently modifying threads, while the other thread will be stored into `myThread`.

Comment: @GiulioFranco Amazing strategy to find the offending thread, I will add it to the answer asap.

Comment: Rethinking about it, the ArrayList iterator already does that: "The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException."

Comment: Even easier: just debug into the code and set a watchpoint on the ArrayList's internal size variable.

Comment: The problem is, it looks like they are not safe as said (at least in a specific implementation). If the said iterator are really safe It should have thrown a ConcurrentModificationException instead of a NoSuchElementException in any case of changing after iterating. Please, help me if I am wrong.